# eOS Hera doesn't start after shutdown and starts normally after reboot

Tags: boot, release-hera

After shutdown eOS Hera starts in console mode, but after reboot it starts normally. After the command "journalctl -xb | grep failed" I see this:

```
dec 20 16:49:30 veil-pc kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
dec 20 16:49:25 veil-pc systemd-udevd[519]: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
dec 20 16:49:26 veil-pc systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
dec 20 16:49:26 veil-pc systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
dec 20 16:49:26 veil-pc systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job local-fs.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 20 16:49:26 veil-pc systemd[1]: boot-efi.mount: Job boot-efi.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
dec 20 16:49:26 veil-pc systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F571\x2d4F82.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F571\x2d4F82.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

This is my /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6ff479fb-e132-4a19-8f75-dc1b1ce9c3c4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=F571-4F82  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       0
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have "FAST BOOT" option in your BIOS? I remember having issues when that was enabled and after a reboot all the "fast boot" data was discarded and systems started normally.

give it a try and let me know, pls.
-Aldo

Comment: Fast Boot is disabled

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Filesystem can't be mounted because of some dependency issues. Do you have SecureBoot enabled in BIOS or LegacyBoot

Comment: Only one option "Other PCI Device ROM Priority" was set to UEFI. I changed it to Legacy. I'll write about results later.

Comment: Now the system starts normally. So that was the problem. Thank you for your help!